# Почему этот код вызывает бесконечную рекурсию? Почему перенос описания сканера внутрь метода решает проблему?

Tags: java, рекурсия

Есть два варианта кода, которые отличаются только тем, как описан используемый в коде сканер. При использовании сканера, описанного как локальная переменная метода, код работает, а при использовании такого же сканера, описанного как поле объекта, возникает бесконечная рекурсия и переполнение стека. Почему?

Вариант 1 (все работает):

```
  public class Logic {

    void smth() {
      try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);//сканер
        System.out.println("Введите число");
        int input = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println(input);
        smth();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Доступны только цифры");
        smth();
      }
    }

  }
```

Вариант 2 (бесконечная рекурсия):

```
  public class Logic {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); //сканер

    void smth() {
      try {
        System.out.println("Введите число");
        int input = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println(input);
        smth();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Доступны только цифры");
        smth();
      }
    }
```

Вот что получается при запуске второго варианта кода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не приводите в вопросах картинки. Приводите вывод программы и распечатку стека в виде текста.

Comment: попробуйте открыть это сообщение на телефоне и поймете почему(это относится к комменту выше)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во втором варианте кода переполнение стека возникает после первого же ошибочного ввода, поскольку возникает исключение, при обработке исключения рекурсивно вызывается метод `smth()`, который тут же пытается ввести из сканера новое значение, но поскольку к этому моменту с клавиатуры не введено нового числа, то снова возникает исключение, рекурсивно вызывается `smth()`, он пытается ввести число, возникает исключение, рекурсивно вызывается `smth()`, он пытается ввести число, возникает исключение, рекурсивно вызывается `smth()`, он пытается ввести число, возникает исключение, рекурсивно вызывается `smth()`, он пытается ввести число, возникает исключение, .... В общем, получается сказка о попе и его любимой собаке.

В первом варианте, при описании сканера в качестве локальной переменной, при каждом входе в метод создается и инициализируется новый сканер. Этот новый сканер ничего не знает про горькую участь прежнего и всегда добросовестно ждет нового ввода. При вводе недопустимого значения (не числа) точно так же возникает исключение и рекурсивно вызывается `smth()`, но это не приводит к немедленному повторному возбуждению исключения, поскольку при этом опять создается новый сканер, который опять ждет ввода.

Однако это отнюдь не решение проблемы, это лишь отсрачивание проблемы. Вы можете легко в этом убедиться, если введете несколько тысяч значений. В один прекрасный момент, после двух или трех или пяти тысяч введенных значений, вы получите точно то же самое переполнение стека, так как рекурсия у вас по-прежнему остается бесконечной, только она происходит не так быстро. Вы можете проверить это, запустив свой код с небольшой добавкой, которая покажет, что у вас происходит с вложенностью вызовов и с памятью:

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.MemoryMXBean;
import java.lang.management.MemoryUsage;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ru_So_964841 {

  public static class Logic {

    private int nesting = 0;
    private MemoryMXBean mxbean = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean();

    void smth() {
      nesting++;

      MemoryUsage usage =  mxbean.getNonHeapMemoryUsage();
      long used = usage.getUsed(), commited = usage.getCommitted();
      System.out.printf("Commited: %,d, used: %,d, available: %,d, nesting = %s\n", 
                        commited, used, commited - used, nesting);

      try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); //сканер
        System.out.println("Введите число");
        int input = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println(input);
        smth();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Доступны только цифры");
        smth();
      }
      nesting--;
    }

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Logic().smth();
  }

}
```

Настоящее решение проблемы получится в том случае, если неукоснительно соблюдать следующие обязательные для любой правильной программы требования:

**1. Всегда перед вводом со сканера убеждаться, что у сканера есть данные для ввода.**

Сканер имеет методы семейства `hasNext...` для разных типов данных, и всякий ввод со сканера следует предварять проверкой типа

```
if (scanner.hasNextInt()) i = scanner.nextInt();
```

или

```
while (scanner.hasNextInt()) { 
  i = scanner.nextInt(); 
  doWhatYouNeed(1); 
}
```

**2. Всегда после использования сканера закрывать его.**

Сканер -- это ресурс, который занимает память и ресуррсы ОС, его следует всегда закрывать после использования, иначе даже и без бесконечной рекурсии может возникнуть утечка ресурсов и крах приложения. Это же касается и потоков ввода-вывода, файлов и т. п. Код в общем случае должен быть примерно такой:

```
try {
  scanner = new Scanner(...);
  while (scanner.hasNextInt()) { 
    i = scanner.nextInt(); 
    doWhatYouNeed(1); 
} finally { 
  if (scanner != null) scanner.close(); 
}
```

Я не знаю как вашa IDE, а `Eclipse` даже предупреждает при несоблюдении этого требования: `Resource leak: 'scanner' is never closed`. Обращайте внимание на предупреждения -- проблемы будут реже встречаться.

**3. Всегда убеждаться, что рекурсия будет конечной во всех случаях.**

При анализе кода рекурсивного метода всегда нужно убедиться, что при его выполнении **неизбежно** наступит ситуация, когда рекурсивный вызов больше не будет происходить. Например, в хрестоматийном рекурсивном вычислении факториала

```
long factorial(long n) {
    if (n < 2) return 1;
    return n * factorial(n - 1);
}
```

мы можем убедиться, что при каждом очередном вызове метода аргумент будет меньше, чем аргумент у вызывающего метода, таким образом рано или поздно аргумент вызванного метода станет меньше двух, и рекурсивные вызовы больше выполняться не будут, а произойдет возврат из всех рекурсивно вызванных методов.

Вообще с рекурсией следует обращаться аккуратно. Чаще всего у любого рекурсивного метода есть итеративный (не рекурсивный) вариант решения, который по быстродействию и расходу памяти намного лучше. Рекурсию следует использовать там, где задача рекурсивна по своей природе и рекурсивная реализация существенно упрощает код и/или облегчает понимание (учебные задачи типа факториала, разбор синтаксических конструкций и т. п.), в других случаях стоит десять раз подумать. В вашей задаче я не вижу совершенно никакого смысла использовать рекурсию, это итеративная по своей природе задача, попытки применить здесь рекурсию не дают никакого выигрыша и только усложняют ситуацию.

Comment: + хороший ответ

Answer (score 3):

Потому что `scanner.nextInt();`, вызвавший исключение, остается на том же месте (не продвигается) во входном потоке.